# JavaScript for Media Web Part in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, web-part

I have some custom JavaScript in SharePoint 2010 that works with the native Media Web Part, as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558890%28v=office.14%29.aspx). However, when porting this over to SharePoint 2013, the `obj[0].Content.MediaPlayer` element is no longer accessible.

Is there some new way of accessing the MediaPlayer object in 2013, or has the JavaScript functionality been removed entirely?

The code I am using is from the getMediaPlayer() function MSDN has provided:
`$("object")[0].Content.MediaPlayer`

The JavaScript error: `TypeError: $(...)[0].Content is undefined`

Comment: Can you please post relevant code. Also the exact error you are getting.

Comment: I've added the code and the error.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/sharepoint-custom-media-video-player-using-jquery-20639.aspx)

Comment: This appears to use the same getMediaPlayer logic as the MSDN link does. All of the code works in SharePoint 2010, but this getMediaPlayer logic is what's failing in 2013.

Comment: From the link I shared it seems the same function is working on 2013. Are you using custom master page and CSS? You can use developer tool to check how the object is rendered.

Comment: I'm using custom master pages and CSS, but I don't know how this would affect that. The $("object") is being accessed correctly, it just does not have the "Content" attached to it.